# Drag and drop uploading works, but not input click

Tags: javascript

Ok I have the following code which works fine when dragging and dropping the image into a box.

```
function drop(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

    var filesArray = event.dataTransfer.files;
    for (var i=0; i<filesArray.length; i++)
    {
     var progressDiv = document.getElementById('progressDiv');
     var pbar = document.createElement('progress');
     var br = document.createElement('br');
     var report = document.createElement('div');

     pbar.setAttribute('id', 'progressBar' + i);
     pbar.setAttribute('value', '0');
     pbar.setAttribute('max', '100');
     report.setAttribute('id', 'report' + i)

     progressDiv.appendChild(pbar);
     progressDiv.appendChild(br);
     progressDiv.appendChild(report);
     progressDiv.appendChild(br);

     sendFile(filesArray[i]);
    }
}
```

However when I change the code slightly to try and upload it if a user manually click the input type file button it for odd reason does not run.

```
    function handleFiles(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  var files = document.getElementById("ppupload").files[0]; 
    alert(files);
    var filesArray = files;
    for (var i=0; i<filesArray.length; i++)
    {
     var progressDiv = document.getElementById('progressDiv');
     var pbar = document.createElement('progress');
     var br = document.createElement('br');
     var report = document.createElement('div');

     pbar.setAttribute('id', 'progressBar' + i);
     pbar.setAttribute('value', '0');
     pbar.setAttribute('max', '100');
     report.setAttribute('id', 'report' + i)

     progressDiv.appendChild(pbar);
     progressDiv.appendChild(br);
     progressDiv.appendChild(report);
     progressDiv.appendChild(br);

     sendFile(filesArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Is there away to make this get the file and submit it?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+I and tell us what it prints

Comment: There is no error message in console @SamuelLiew

Answer (score 0):

fixed the issue by removing the for loop

```
function handleFiles(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  var filesArray = document.getElementById("ppupload").files[0]; 

     var progressDiv = document.getElementById('progressDiv');
     var pbar = document.createElement('progress');
     var br = document.createElement('br');
     var report = document.createElement('div');

     pbar.setAttribute('id', 'progressBar' + i);
     pbar.setAttribute('value', '0');
     pbar.setAttribute('max', '100');
     report.setAttribute('id', 'report' + i)

     progressDiv.appendChild(pbar);
     progressDiv.appendChild(br);
     progressDiv.appendChild(report);
     progressDiv.appendChild(br);

     sendFile(filesArray[i]);

}
```